Flutter build issue with gradle
I'm getting the following issues in my project after updating dart. It was working fine last week but cant get build to run now.
ERROR:C:\Users\...\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\0e643d5da6fcb9481b0522bb4a3cd61b\transformed\lifecycle-livedata-core-2.8.2-runtime.jar: D8: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.length()" because "<parameter1>" is null

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeExtDexDebug'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform lifecycle-livedata-core-2.8.2.aar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-core:2.8.2) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, asm-transformed-variant=NONE, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-enable-jacoco-instrumentation=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=28, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for DexingNoClasspathTransform: C:\Users\....\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\0e643d5da6fcb9481b0522bb4a3cd61b\transformed\lifecycle-livedata-core-2.8.2-runtime.jar.
         > Error while dexing.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

I've tried adding dependences like old post suggested and also added multiDexEnabled true but nothing seems to work

not sure about flutter but some unsupported dependency version must be causing this issue.
In native android reducing

androidx.navigation:navigation-compose

and

androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-compose

verison was fix for me.
